# Instantiating Multiple AbstractConcreteBase Issue

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm getting an error I don't understand with AbstractConcreteBase

in my_enum.py

```
class MyEnum(AbstractConcreteBase, Base):
    pass
```

in enum1.py

```
class Enum1(MyEnum):
    years = Column(SmallInteger, default=0)

# class MyEnums1:
#    NONE = Enum1()
#    Y1 = Enum1(years=1)
```

in enum2.py

```
class Enum2(MyEnum):
    class_name_python = Column(String(50))
```

in test.py

```
from galileo.copernicus.basic_enum.enum1 import Enum1
from galileo.copernicus.basic_enum.enum2 import Enum2
#...
```

If I uncomment the three lines in enum1.py I get the following error on the second import.

AttributeError: type object 'MyEnum' has no attribute '**table**'

but without MyEnums1 it works fine or with MyEnums1 in a separate file it works fine.  Why would this instantiation affect the import?  Is there anyway I can keep MyEnums1 in the same file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the purpose of the abstractconcretebase is to apply a non-standard order of operations to the standard mapping procedure.   normally, mapping works like this:

1. define a class to be mapped
2. define a Table
3. map the class to the Table using mapper().

Declarative essentially combines these three steps, but that's what it does.

When using an abstract concrete base, we have this totally special step that needs to happen - the base class needs to be mapped to a *union* of all the tables that the subclasses are mapped to.  So if you have enum1 and enum2, the "Base" needs to map to essentially "select * from enum1 UNION ALL select * from enum2".

This mapping to a UNION can't happen piecemeal; the MyEnum base class has to present itself to mapper() with the full UNION of every sub-table at once.   So AbstractConcreteBase performs the complex task of rearranging how declarative works such that the base MyEnum is not mapped at all until the [mapper configuration](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/mapper_config.html?highlight=mapper%20configuration#sqlalchemy.orm.configure_mappers) occurs, which among other places occurs when you first instantiate a mapped class.   It then inserts itself as the mapped base for all the existing mapped subclasses.

So basically by instantiating an Enum1() object at the class level like that, you're invoking configure_mappers() way too early, such that by the time Enum2() comes along the abstractconcretebase is baked and the process fails.

All of that aside, it's not at all correct to be instantiating a mapped class like Enum1() at the class level like that.  ORM-mapped objects are the complete opposite of global objects and must always be created local to a specific Session.

edit: also those classes are supposed to have {"concrete": True} on them which is part of why you're getting this message.  Im trying to see if the message can be improved.

edit 2: yeah the mechanics here are weird.   I've committed something else that skips this particular error message, though it will fail differently now and not much better.   getting this to fail more gracefully would require a little more work.